# Modbus-tk CPU load reduce

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tk

Thank you very much for the answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21459211/3882432).

Where can I find this file?

> ...after modifying the **`modbus_rtu.py'** in the following way...

I'm using Raspbian, tried to find and replace the code in these files:

```
pi@rpiplc00 / $ sudo find / -name "modbus_rtu.py" -print
/home/pi/distr/modbustk/modbus_tk/modbus_rtu.py
/home/pi/distr/modbustk/build/lib.linux-armv6l-2.7/modbus_tk/modbus_rtu.py
```

but it didn't reduce CPU load.

Cheers.