# Bad performance of `ModbusSerialClient`, as fast as the timeout

Tags: python, modbus, rs485

For a project I have 4 modbus devices connected on a RS485 serial line. The devices are working fine and now that I'm writing a controller I'm quite unhappy with the performance of `pymodbus`.

I found this thread [Python modbus library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081442/python-modbus-library) and it seems to me that there may be better python modbus libraries out there. `pymodbus` is easy to use and I'd rather like to continue using it if possible.

However I've found out that the time any read/write routine takes to return is equal to the timeout. This doesn't seem right to me so I wrote a quick test:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import  ModbusSerialClient
import time

for t in xrange(1, 11):
    client = ModbusSerialClient("rtu", port="/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600, timeout=t)

    start = time.time()
    data = client.read_holding_registers(0x9000, count=7, unit=2)
    stop = time.time()

    if data:
        succ = "was successful"
    else:
        succ = "failed"

    print "timeout: %ss, read %s, time spent reading: %fs" % (t, succ, stop-start)
```

and this is the output I got

```
timeout: 1s, read was successful, time spent reading: 1.039731s
timeout: 2s, read was successful, time spent reading: 2.038965s
timeout: 3s, read was successful, time spent reading: 3.041441s
timeout: 4s, read was successful, time spent reading: 4.040762s
timeout: 5s, read was successful, time spent reading: 5.043523s
timeout: 6s, read was successful, time spent reading: 6.040139s
timeout: 7s, read was successful, time spent reading: 7.042159s
timeout: 8s, read was successful, time spent reading: 8.045216s
timeout: 9s, read was successful, time spent reading: 9.047682s
timeout: 10s, read was successful, time spent reading: 10.048799s
```

I've tested it with different RS845<->USB converters and I always get similar results.

Can anyboby else confirm this? Or am I missing some not-documented argument there that would increase `ModbusSerialClient`'s performance?

Comment: hmmm that is weird, is it on a full or half duplex? Also sometimes the electrical stack exchange has some good info about this, since sometimes it may be setup and not software related.

Comment: I use only 2 wires, so I believe this is half duplex, right? Anyway I don't think it has anything to the serial line itself. I added another RS845<->USB converter to the line and wrote a modbus sniffer. I could see that the devices already sent the answers but `pymodbus` read function was still waiting until the timeout.

Comment: maybe have a look at the source code https://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus i would do it and try to see if there is anything that is like wait until time out then print response or whatever. but am at work now

Comment: yeah, I'll take a look later at the code

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that - pymodbus always waits for the timeout(1-3 seconds) even if it receives response from slave immediately(in my case 14ms). So I tested with minimalmodbus and  received the response immediately.In my case up to 35 times per second when I tested it with a loop.

Edit: I found the reason - pymodbus waits for over 1000 bytes or timeout when using RTU protocol. They need to calculate expected bytes, and they have a fix for this, but this is not yet in the main branch(AFAIK). Check this post https://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/issues/76 So if you really need to use pymodbus you could try the patches.

Comment: @MartinEvans Why not?

Comment: @MartinEvans My original post answered part of the question - Pablo asked if somebody can confirm that - I was the first one to confirm that with details. Today I added second part of the answer - the reason and possible fix.