# How can I fix SyntaxError: invalid syntax/ import * from modbus?

Tags: python, windows, pip, exe, modbus

I want to get the .exe file from a code source but doing `python main.py build` results in this error:

```py
C:\MyProject>python main.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
import parserz as parser
File "C:\MyProject\parserz.py", line 9
import * from modbus
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea please? 
Maybe a problem with pip?

Answer (score 1):

In python you import like this

```
from modbus import *
```

Also, In python its good practice to import only what you need.

So you shouldn't use `from .... import *` instead use

```
from modbus import something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either import the module and run all normal code with

```py
import modbus
```

or you can import all the classes, functions, variables, etc., from the file to use later in your code with

```py
from modbus import *
```

---

To illustrate my point:

If you have two files **my_imports.py** and **main.py** that contain the following code:

***my_imports.py:***

```py
print('Imported module my_imports')

def add_nums(a,b):
    return a+b

def another_function():
    return 'this function was also called'
```

***(version 1) main.py:***

```py
import my_imports

# this code would fail because the function isn't imported
print(add_nums(5,7))
```

***(version 2) main.py:***

```py
from my_imports import *

print(add_nums(5,7))
print(another_function())
```

- **In verion 1 of main.py** you would see `Imported module my_imports` in the output but your code would fail when you try to use the
  `add_nums` function defined in **my_imports.py**.
- **In version 2 of main.py** you would still see `Imported module my_imports` in the output but you would also see the result of calling the other two functions in the output as they are now available for use in **main.py**:

```py
12
this function was also called
```

As mentioned in some of the other answers, you can also just import the functionality you want from another python script. For example, if you only wanted to use the add_nums method, you could instead have

```py
from my_imports import add_nums
```

in your **main.py**.

Comment: In which file ? I have 3 files: main.py, parserz.py and modbus.py and I have already add modbus in parserz.py with this line:  import * from modbus

Comment: Change `import * from modbus` to `from modbus import *` in your parserz.py file if this is the only place you require the modbus functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `from modbus import *` should be enough. But it is generally not a good idea to import all so I recommend `import modbus as mb`. Also you might want to look into modbus libraries like pyModbus or minimalModbus. Here's a good link depicting their pros and cons: [Python modbus library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081442/python-modbus-library)